# Memory usage VS. CPU usage in the iphone

Tags: iphone, opengl, memory-management

I'm writing a small game in OpenGL, where I represent Items, enemies, characters, etc with a class. Each class saves references to one or more objects from an Animation class. An animation class contains references to one or more frames, which are textures I already loaded using OpenGL. Whenever I rotate, scale, etc any element in the game I save the data of such transformations. Right now  I recalculate ( I don't use the transformations provided by OpenGL) the coordinates of each texture each frame at the moment of drawing, without saving them.

Not like I'm trying to optimize already, but I wonder which one is the best approach when programming for iPhone... It's better to save in your objects all the information you need ?... or It's better to re-calculate and leave most of the work to the CPU.

Comment: So are you more concerned with if the iPhone can handle this type of calculation frequency without a problem, or are you just wondering if this design is sound? Both? Neither? Having a hard time figuring out what you want/need exactly...

Comment: Also, is the code at least working? If it's already working then I'd say, yeah, you are sort of optimizing early. Work on the rest of the stuff and revisit this if you find the game to be running slowly.

Comment: @Kyle
My code works fine..but Yep, It's the first, I wonder about the iphone capacity to make calculations with frequency every frame...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much data are you talking about, it seems like any transform information or coordinates are going to be trivially small compared to things like the actual textures.

I am guessing you are looking at between 8 and 64 bytes per on sprites, and at most maybe ~250 sprits? That will probably be less than 1 frame of animation for on sprite, and depending on the exact size of your objects and the extra data it might not take any extra space because of the granularity of the system malloc.

In other words, unless I am guessing wrong your data is completely in the noise and probably undetectable, definitely cache the values between frames.